# how do I make only certain roles use this command?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

how do I make only certain roles use this command?

````
  if (!message.member.hasPermission()) return;
  if (mention == null) return;
  if (message.guild.member(mention).hasPermission()) return;
  let reason = message.content.slice (prefix.lenght + mention.toString().lenght + 5);
  message.cannel.send (mention.username + );
  mention.sendMessage ().then (d_msg => {
    messge.guild.member(mention).ban(reason);
  })
}```
````

Comment: A little typo at the let reason part. `prefix.lenght` should be `prefix.length`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `GuildMember`'s roles to check if they have the role

Using the role's name

```js
if (!message.member.roles.some(role => role.name === 'Role Name')) return
```

Or using the role's ID

```js
if (!message.member.roles.some(role => role.id === 'Role_ID')) return
```